# change the asp button behaviour

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2019

When creating a form using an ***ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)*** template, I have a TextBox that holds a string of characters and 2 buttons, one to reset the form and one to submit the form... When filling in the form the "**reset**" button works the same way as the "**submit**" button, in that the "**required**" tag is triggered if the textbox is empty when the user clicks the reset button. I can't seem to get the button behaviour to work correctly.

Is there a way to set the "**reset**" button to not trigger the textbox "**required**" tag?

Example of my code;

```
<h3>Account Number</h3>
<asp:TextBox ID="AccountNumber" name="AccountNumber" MaxLength="18" placeholder="2347655454" required="required" runat="server" Width="300px" Height="40px" Font-Size="Large"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Reset Form" Width="300" Height="50px" Font-Bold="True" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" ForeColor="Black" OnClick="reset_Click" />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Submit Form" Width="300" Height="50px" Font-Bold="True" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" ForeColor="Black" OnClick="Mong_Click" />
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a standard HTML <input type="reset" .../> That way it won't trigger a form post. You can still use CSS to style it.

Comment: This behaviour is happening because you do a postback when you click any button. And that causes the required tag to fire. 

You can try setting the ReadOnly property of the textbox to false.

Comment: @davidP Within the form there is also an <asp:Calendar that I would like to reset too, but a standard <input type="reset" doesn't appear to reset those.

Comment: @Proliges just tried the ReadOnly property option, still get the same behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why bother with the required tag? Just put the logic in your button code.

```
if (Textbox1.Text == "") {
   // logic here to tell user they have to enter some data
   // you can even use registerscript and pop open a client side
   // dialog
   return
  }
```

So, since in 99% of cases we assume that some text will be entered, then suffering a post back once in a blue moon should not really matter in the scope of things, should it?

I would just put the logic in the button event code, and not really worry about this all that much.